# How to display an image in a block?

Tags: html, css, image, position

I want to display an image in the background in a block. My problem is that this image is distorted (stretched across the width).

I don't need to display the whole image, I want it to take the full width of the block, but it must be centered in height even if the height is hidden.

For example, I want it to look like this :

https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/21/03/56/landscape-1844226_960_720.png

```
element.style {
    background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/21/03/56/landscape-1844226_960_720.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I don't know how to apply the same style on an `img` element. Here is my code :

```
.node--view-mode-similar .layout {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 1rem 1rem 0.2rem 1rem;
    border: 2px solid #ced8dd;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArbNG.png)

```
.node--view-mode-similar .block-field-blocknodearticlefield-article-image img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51Z6c.png)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this:

```
object-fit: cover;
```

Comment: thank you, it works with mobile ios and android without problem?

Comment: you're welcome and yes, I think.